# scrollablePlotArea does not work as expected

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I am creating react-typescript app and I am using Gantt chart.
I tried to use scrollablePlotArea to achieve this result here

````
```https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s013uqa5/```
````

But in my case this scrollbar does not behave similar to the above example.
Here is my code

```
https://codepen.io/manshi44/pen/zYMZYXO?editors=0010
```

[image]
Please see the highlighted part of the image. I dont want to see these when i am scrolling.
Am i missing something or this is expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `chart.scrollablePlotArea` you should use `yAxis.scrollbar`:

```js
yAxis: {
  max: 5,
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true,
    showFull: false
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f4ym1d2c/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.scrollbar